# fullcalendar v2 swap event source

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to display a few fullcalendars using the jquery fullcalendar plug in. Each one is displayed in seperate tabs.

On one of the tabs I've created a fullcalendar. The event source is a remote database and supplying json event data. I've added a checkbox to the page to enable the user to show or hide certain types of events. I found this tutorial which helped: (http://www.mikesmithdev.com/blog/jquery-full-calendar/)

My problem is I'm getting an error that I can'y work out:

Here's is my reload function:

```
function reloadCal(directSale) {

hideDirectSale = (directSale ? 1 : "showDS");
var activeTab = $("#myTab li.active a");
console.log("active tab", activeTab.data('source'));
var sourceURL = '/eventslist/' + activeTab.data('source');

var newSource = {
    url: sourceURL,
    data: {
        ds: hideDirectSale
    },
    currentTimezone: 'Europe/London' // an option!
};
console.log("newsource:", sourceURL);
$('.full-calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSource', sourceURL);
$('.full-calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
$('.full-calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', newSource);
$('.full-calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');

eventSource = newSource;
}
```

Currently the source is not changed - it tried to load the source but comes up with this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clone' of null
```

I think it may be because I am referencing the source incorrectly. `source` within the code is simply a key in an array with urls for the calendars my page will eventually display.

If I remove the first `refetchevents` I can get the calendar to reload with the expected filtered results but the error still persists

Is there a method within fullcalendar to GET the calendars eventSource to ensure I reference it correctly?

Thank you

Comment: It may be that you are changing the sourceURL. On page load, set the sourceURL. When you run `reloadCal`, you should only be setting newSourceURL. Then the last line should be `sourceURL = newSourceURL`.

Comment: Hi - I found out the problem. Because I have a number of fulcalendars on the page each one has a common class but also a unique class. I was referencing with the general class and not the unique class. All works exaclty as your tutorial now - thank you.